# Can attachments be added to emails sent from Nintex Workflow 365 or a standard SP2013 workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

Can attachments be added to emails sent from Nintex Workflow 365 or a standard SP2013 workflow? I can't see a way to do this in either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Nintex, but OOB SharePoint workflows can't.
Anyway, I suppose you mean attach a list attachment. In this case, you'd have to write a custom workflow action, like this one:

[SharePoint 2010 Send Emails With Attachments - Workflow Activity](http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/)